# Angular cli karma can't use json file

Tags: karma-jasmine, angular8, angular-cli-v8

Am using Jasmine karma in angular-cli project.

When am trying to use a json file inside it throws an error.

```
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
describe('xxxService', () => { 
let service: xxxService
let attributeData: any = require('../../mock-data/testCase_mockData/attributedata.json');   
beforeEach(()=>{
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
        providers: [xxxService],
    });
    service = TestBed.get(ColorCodeEngineService);
   // attributeData  = Object.assign({}, require('../../mock-data/testCase_mockData/attributedata.json'));
});
});
```

It throws error ,

> ERROR in ./src/app/mock-data/testCase_mockData/attributedata.json
>   Module parse failed: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near
>   '' You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near ''

Is there any solutions to fix this ?